# Consider a matrix, every column is a vector of [1,2,3....,n] but shuffled order, does this matrix have a name or some special properties?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

I encountered an interesting kind of matrices.

Consider a matrix like this:

$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\2&3&1\\3&1&2\\\end{bmatrix}$

Every column of the matrix consists of [1,2,3,...,n], but every column has a random order (so can be unsymmetric). I know one specific example of this matrix is Toeplitz matrix. Does this kind of shaffled toeplitz matrix have a name? Is there any properties of this kind matrix has already been studied?

Comment: It depends on which orders you want. There are $n!$ different orders but you can only pick $n$ of them. A standard choice is to pick cyclic permutations, which gets you what are called circulant matrices (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix).

Comment: In general, the matrix that is "Toeplitz" in the reverse order, is a [Hankel matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_matrix). The yours is a special case of Hankel matrix, it is circulant, as Qiaochu Yuan writes.

Comment: @jason And yes, circulant matrices have a lot of important properties relating to the discrete Fourier transform